# Subprocess returns after a couple seconds with no error, but command didn't do its job

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

There is a subprocess.run() command I'm using (1):

```py
    p = subprocess.run([
        '/home/ubuntu/my_script.sh',
        'my_arg_1',
        'my_arg_2'
    ])
```

If I run the above, the process returns after about 2 seconds (way too short) and doesn't produce the handful of files it's supposed to (nothing is created, as if the program didn't run at all). There is no apparent error or exception.

Now if I run the following from a shell (2):

```
$ /home/ubuntu/my_script.sh my_arg_1 my_arg_2
```

The program runs for about 15 seconds (as expected) and generates the expected files.

I double and tripled-check that the linux command used in (2) and the concatenation of the arguments in (1) are rigorously and precisely the same. Still, no effet.

Am I missing something? Could there be user permission issues? How comes subprocess.run() returns after a couple of seconds and not immediately, if it's not running the target command?

**EDIT:**

The actual command is as follows:

```
/home/ubuntu/DataScience/alphapose_dress.sh /home/ubuntu/dresses/whole-dresses/VahT2ei1no.jpg /home/ubuntu/dresses/alphapose_results
```

So no, it's not related to relative paths issues

**EDIT2:**

The following:

```py
cmd = [
    config.alphapose_script,
    img_path,
    config.alphapose_outdir
]

with Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True) as p:
    for line in p.stdout:
        print(line, end='')
```

... prints or outputs absolutely nothing. Whereas the actual command when run from a shell outputs many lines.

Comment: Try to add parameter "shell=True" to the call.

Comment: what @MichaelButscher but take into account that its generally considered dangerous to use `shell=True` especially if there is user input involved

Comment: just did that, absolutely no effect — still the exact same behaviour

Comment: I would guess that it's a difference in current working directory between the two scenarios, possibly causing the script to fail because it can't find/create some file that's being referenced with a relative pathname.

Comment: @jasonharper see my edit — basically, I don't think it's that

Comment: Few things to try: (1) add something like "date > /tmp/i_was_here.txt" at the beginning of your shell script to check if it actually gets called. (2) Ensure script is chmod +x and that it has a shellbang ("#!/bin/bash") at the start. (3) add capture_output=True to subprocess.run() and post what you get if you add print(repr(p)).

Comment: @jurez good advice — (1) I can see that yes the script is actually called. (2) yes there's a shebang and the script is executable — (3) the output returns `-1`

Comment: @Jivan If the script is actually being called, comment out everything in it and put just "echo script running; sleep 100; echo script finished". Does it work then?

Comment: @jurez yes it does. Also, thanks to Kharadi's answer I was able to printout stderr in clear form (instead of a chain of bytes) — an error is definitely happening, although I still have to know what causes it, actually now I have a traceback

Comment: @jurez life lesson: always capture stdout and stderr when calling subprocess.run()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

`from subprocess import run,PIPE
 p = run([
        '/home/ubuntu/my_script.sh',
        'my_arg_1',
        'my_arg_2'
    ], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
print(p.stderr)`

It will printout the error.

Comment: You are a hero.